# Is it needed to use more than one computer for master slave replication?

Tags: postgresql, master-slave

I am trying to create master slave replication physically with postgresql11 in debian10. I got same errors from different linux dists so is it something related making the replication in same computer? Or something related with master-slave accounts ?

```
root@dlp:~# vi /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = replica 
synchronous_standby_names = '*'
wal_keep_segments = 10
```

I configured the pg_hba.conf as follows:

```
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    replication     rep_user         127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     rep_user         10.0.0.30/32            trust
host    replication     rep_user         10.0.0.51/32            trust
```

After this segment:
#i didnt create new user as node1 i just used my root/postgres account for all the processes

```
root@node01:~# systemctl stop postgresql

root@node01:~# rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/*

root@node01:~# su - postgres

postgres@node01:~$ pg_basebackup -R -h dlp.srv.world -U rep_user -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -P
```

I got the following error:

pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "dlp.srv.world" (180.43.145.38) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

also in the root account postgres is working fine but i doest show that port 5432 listening?

netstat -nlt

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

when i check the status of "postgresql" is says active but when i type :

```
systemctl status postgresql@11-main
Dec 14 06:20:52 debian postgresql@11-main[6260]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl /
Dec 14 06:20:52 debian postgresql@11-main[6260]: pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/11/
Dec 14 06:20:52 debian systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/pos
Dec 14 06:20:52 debian systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol
Dec 14 06:20:52 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
```

i got that error.

Comment: If you have primary and standby on the same machine (which can only make sense for functionality tests), you have to use different ports for the instances.

Comment: Also, don't `rm -r` the master which you wish to replicate.  That certainly makes replicating it difficult.